# finding values for absolute convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-value

Find all values of real number p or which the series converges:

$$\sum \limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k} (k^{p} - 1)}$$

I tried using the root test and the ratio test, but I got stuck on both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p\lt0$, then $\sqrt{k}(k^p-1)\sim-\sqrt{k}$ hence the series diverges. If $p=0$, then $k^p-1=0$ for every $k$ hence the series is undefined. If $p\gt0$, then $\sqrt{k}(k^p-1)\sim k^{p+1/2}$ hence the series converges if and only if $p\gt1/2$.

Comment: Why is it true that if $p<0$ then $\sqrt{k}(k^p-1)$ ~ $-\sqrt{k}$? This would mean that $k^p-1$ ~ $-1$ in the limit, but that is not the case as p is fixed? Might be wrong, but...

Comment: If $p\lt0$ ($p$ fixed, of course!), then $k^p\to0$ when $k\to+\infty$.

Comment: Oh,yeah I've read it in my head as p<1, beats me why -.-

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I've been trying to figure this stuff out for hours

Answer (score 0):

Let $p>1$, so since $$\lim_{k\to+\infty}k^p\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(k^p-1)}<\infty$$ then for $p>1$ the series is convergent.

Comment: why can you multiply it by k^{p}?

Comment: I wanted to use the comparison test.

Comment: Yeah but then $a_{n}/b_{n}$ in the limit would be $1/k^p$ which is $0$ so it doesn't work?

Comment: @Belov: Theorem: Let $\sum u_n$ and $\lim n^pu_n<\infty$ so if $p>1$ then the series is convergent.

Comment: Why are u looking at $\lim n^pu_{n}$ then and not the sum of that series?

Comment: $\ddot\smile\quad$

Answer (score 0):

By cauchy's condensation test $$\frac{2^k}{2^{kp + k/2} - 2^{k/2}} = \frac{1}{2^{kp - k/2} - \frac{1}{2^{k/2}}} \simeq \frac{1}{2^{kp - k/2}}.$$ If we now use the ratio test for the series $\sum_k \frac{1}{2^{kp - k/2}}$ we obtain $$\frac{2^{kp - k/2}}{2^{kp - k/2} \cdot 2^{p - 1/2}} \to \frac{1}{2^{p-1/2}} < 1 \Longleftrightarrow p > 1/2.$$